# What is the purpose of d-char-sequence in C++ raw strings?

Tags: c++

On this reference: **https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal**, raw string is defined as:

```
 prefix(optional) R"d-char-sequence(optional)(r-char-sequence(optional))d-char-sequence(optional)"
```

Example:

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
  World
)foo";
```

What is the purpose of the d-char-sequence ("foo" in the example above)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The optional `d-char-sequence` is used to define the end marker of the raw string.

For example, if the raw string contains the substring `)"`, then the line:

`const char* s = R"(string with )" inside)";`

will raise a syntax error. This can be fixed by using the optional `d-char-sequence` that is not met inside the raw string:

`const char* s = R"uniq(string with )" inside)uniq";`

Answer (score 6):

It lets you embed `)"` in the literal, which would otherwise be considered the end of the literal.